# Android tabs - set custom view issue

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm trying to make some tabs with a custom view. Here is my code

```
View tabContent = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_content, null);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TextView tabText = (TextView) tabContent.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

tabText.setText("Tab 1");
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabContent));

tabText.setText("Tab 2");
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabContent));

tabText.setText("Tab 3");
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabContent));
```

But it renders me just the third tab

[image]

Now, the curios thing is that if I try to set just text, as follows:

`tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
 tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));`

everything works fine (the text is rendered)... But I need that custom view because of that counter.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: You're setting 1 `TextView tabText` 3 times, last of which is with "Tab 3", that's probably why it stays...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the need to inflate the `tabContent` 3 times because `setCustomView()` method works directly with that instance, so each modification to `tabContent` object will affect the rest of the tabs

Answer (score 1):

Open **Activity.java** and modify and set tab like below code

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne); 


TextView tab2 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab2.setText("TWO");
tab2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tab2);

TextView tab3 = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tab3.setText("THREE");
tab3.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tab3);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
View tabContent = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_content, null);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TextView tabText1 = (TextView) tabContent.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
TextView tabText2 = (TextView) tabContent.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
TextView tabText3 = (TextView) tabContent.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

tabText1.setText("Tab 1");
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabText1);

tabText2.setText("Tab 2");
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabText2);

tabText3.setText("Tab 3");
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabText3);
```